# Formula to automate scheduling tool Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have one worksheet that lists every employees' start and end time for each day of the week. on another worksheet I have that I would like to show the data in colored bars to get a greater look about how many people are working each hour. I would like to insert a "1" into each of the cells that apply to when an employee should be working. I don't know if I need a combination of match,index,if statements. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So are you saying your data worksheet has one row per employee and one column per hour in the work day and fills in 1's in the crossing cells of the table?? Just trying to clarify the starting point.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detail. I have one sheet, called data that has one row per employee with one column stating their start time and one column stating their end time. The other worksheet has one row per employee name and one column for each hour of the day. I would like excel to read the employee name and start time from sheet 1 and link it to sheet 2 by putting a "1" in the cells the employee is supposed to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a COUNTIFS Formula.

On sheet 1, enter in your employee names and their work times, with their start and end times in separate columns. You should have your employees' names in column A, with their start time on Monday in column B, their end time for Monday in column C, their start time for Tuesday in column D, etc. Format your start and end time cells as Times.

On sheet 2, create a table with days of the week as the column headers starting in column B and skipping every other column in row 1 (Monday in col B, Tues in D, etc), and each hour of your work day down column A starting in row 2.

On sheet 2 enter this formula in B2:

```
    =COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!B$2:B$#ofEmployees,"<="&$A2,'Sheet1'!C$11:C$14,">="&$A3)
```

"#ofEmployees" should not be in your formula. It is simply the number of employees you have. You will need to enter in a number here to complete the range.

Sheet1 is the name of the sheet that your employees' names and their work times are on.

Drag the formula down to the end of your work day. Select the range from B2 to where you dragged down, and drag it across to the end of the week. In every other column, you will see the number of people who will be working that hour.

Select the range from B2 to the end of your table. Under the Home Tab, go to Conditional Formatting and select an appropriate Color Scale.

On sheet 2, hide the columns with blank data in your table (between the days of the week) if you want to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Won't that just count the number of people working each hour? I would like to take the raw data from sheet 1 listing employee names in column A and start time and end time in Column B&C and link that to a second sheet that has hours 0:00-24:00 in row 1, with employee names in column A. If John Doe has a listed start time at 5:00 pm on sheet 1, have the second sheets insert a "1" at the intersection of John Doe and 5:00pm. The end result will hopefully look something like a gant chart.

Comment: Yes, it would. I didn't quite understand what you wanted. I'll post another answer.

Comment: Didn't realize this had been put on hold. What you need is a formula like =IF(AND(hour>=start time, next hour<=end time),1,"") in the table you describe. The "hour" would be the 5:00 pm, and the start time would be the employee's start time. The "next hour" would be the 6:00 pm in the next column of your table. You'll need to stretch from 12 am to 12 am in the column headers and 12 am to 11pm in the table for it to work. You could also add 'Data Bars' conditional formatting for better looks, or set a rule using similar formula to format cells without even using numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for the confusion in the beginning. First time user.

Comment: That's cool. You could also do it with a stacked bar chart, but you would need to have a formula calculating the difference in your start and end time for each person. Select the start, end, and difference along with the names when you choose the chart data range. Flip the rows/columns so your names are on the left side of the chart (listed under horizontal axis). Delete the series for the end time. Format the series for the start time to have no fill. Format the vertical axis to have a major unit of =1/12. Set the Maximum to a fixed value of 1. Set the minor unit to =1/120